# Identify song played on piano in "Under the Lake"

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

I am trying to find out what this song is called I have a 10 second clip and the app Shazam cannot pick it up.

It’s a rock type song at [0:50](https://youtu.be/KPx8VLDCR-k?t=49) on this video from the movie *Under the Lake*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a piano cover of **Nirvana**'s [*Smell Like Teen Spirit*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWKbfoikeg).

It is confirmed by this [review](https://variety.com/2018/film/reviews/under-the-silver-lake-review-1202811006/) in Variety:

> Sam is led to the home of The Songwriter (Jeremy Bobb), who turns out to be…the secret mastermind behind all pop music since the dawn of the counterculture. **He wrote “Smells Like Teen Spirit” on the piano**!